# Python GUI framework for Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, user-interface

I'm trying to find a good "python GUI framework" for Mac OS X, but I haven't found anything good until now, only wxWidgets which I don't like and it's also unstable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [pyqt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) ([pyside](http://www.pyside.org/) should be equivalent but with more relaxed license terms) and I find it pleasing and useful -- I also like the fact that (with no extra effort on my part) it gives me cross-platform apps!-)

[pyobjc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) (comes w/your Mac, works w/Xcode, etc) may be preferable for apps you never want to be cross-platform, but I find it less easily usable than PyQt.  However if you're very skilled in Objective C, Cocoa etc, I imagine pyobjc will feel perfectly natural and usable to *you*!-).

Answer (score 3):

For the most MacOSX you could use [PyObjc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) which basically allows you to write Cocoa apps i python using Interface Builder etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is quite an old question but I'll leave one more suggestion In case any one else Is looking through this for suggestions.

I personally use Tkinter, It works on macOS, Windows and Linux without needing to make changes to the code for each platform. It's got quite a big community so you'll have no problem finding tutorials regarding It.

I began learning Pygame for a project and at times felt It became overcomplicated with setting up the GUI, but then I used Tkinter for a GUI app and was surprised when i saw you could create a window with buttons In a dozen simple lines of code.