# Is there a way to develop OS X applications with python?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python GUI framework for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393514/python-gui-framework-for-mac-os-x)

Is there a way to develop OS X applications with python for mountain lion? I found two libs dedicated to that - pyObjC and py2app, but both of them are very outdated.

Is there still any solutions for building OS X apps with python?

Comment: @Junuxx, thanks for the link - it can be useful. Although, it seems that the only way to use it to build applications with osx gui is to use pyObjC

Answer (score 2):

One of the benefits of OSX is the native support for Python. Almost all Python code you write on Windows or Linux will work on OSX (with the exception of platform dependent functions).

There are many libraries out there which allow you to write graphical applications. http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro is PyQt which allows you to write Qt applications and has OSX support. If you want to do any kind of web app's, there are libraries like Django.

Comment: I know it has (OSX is *nix itself), I was talking about making Apps (.app) that will work in OSX with native GUI.

Comment: what about cocoa? PyOBJC only?