# How to turn Python program into executable file

Tags: python

I apologize for such a basic question.  I've done some research online and still cannot figure out for the life of me how to turn a python folder into something like an actual app I can open in OS X.  I am using Mac OS X, Terminal and Coderunner for my Python project.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "actual app"? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: What do you mean, python folder into an app?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options:

- [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) is not Python-specific. It lets you wrap a simple GUI around a command line tool.
- [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) is Python-specific and a good choice if you have a GUI, or need to run in the background.
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) is similar to py2app but cross-platform; I've never used it, so I don't know how well it works.

The right choice depends on what your program does; who is the expected audience — do you need to redistribute it, if so how, and so forth.  If you want to make the application entirely self-contained — not dependent on anything else beyond the OS — then things get more complicated (though certainly not insoluble; there are several commercial Mac desktop apps written in Python.)

Comment: I'd like to add cx_Freeze to the list which is cross platform: http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It'd be really interesting to see if someone could compare cx_Freeze, PyInstaller and py2app.  cx_Freeze doesn't even mention the Mac on its home page, which probably accounts for its lack of visibility!

Comment: It actually does mention it: "cx_Freeze is cross platform and should work on any platform that Python itself works on"

Comment: As for the comparison, there's something here: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tZ42hjaRunvkObFq0bKxVdg&output.

Comment: I get an error trying to go to that URL.  (I was referring to explicit mention of the Mac on that page.)

Comment: Sorry about that, there is a period missing at the end of the URL: <https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=tZ42hjaRunvkObFq0bKxVdg&output.>

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would make the script executable by putting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line, and then in a terminal window typing

```
chmod u+x myscript.py
```

You might also want to put it in a special `scripts` folder and then add that to your `PATH` by editing `.bash_profile`. (I am putting a lot of buzz-words here to help you find the tutorials explaining how these things work.)

You can [wrap your script into an Automator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469799/is-it-possible-to-create-python-based-application-in-xcode-or-equivalent/15470008#15470008) if you want to try running it that way, but in the long run you will be better off getting comfortable working in a terminal window.

It would also help to know what your app does: Process files, generate a GUI, do a calculation, etc...

Comment: I guess what I mean is if I make a python program with a GUI, how do I then turn that into it's own application that someone else with a mac could install into their applications folder and run.

Comment: I'm not sure if beroe just answered my question.

Comment: If you want to make a GUI, you would probably want to learn some of the tools listed [here](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html) or those listed in @Nicolas_Riley's answer. My suggestion will cover a fair percentage of data-processing-type tasks (including user interaction), but only when used at the command line. I guess I wouldn't give up on terminal-based scripts until you must.